# connection error with SQL Server by double clicking .JAR file

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a strange problem with my jar file. If I run it through cmd with 
    java -jar myjar.jar everything works fine and the application connects succesfully to my SQL Server database, but if I run it through double clicking and I try to connect to my db, it throws an exception:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:82e2f4e5-9827-43df-a5e6-9bb65fc597d2
```

I didn't poste any code because I am sure that this problem is absolutely not code related.

Answer (score 0):

Double clicking on the jar runs using the default environment.  You probably have some settings in the command prompt window where you are typing the java -jar myjar.jar command. Assuming this is a Windows command prompt, run set without any parameters to see your environment variables.  Check to see if you have any related to classpath or javahome, etc.  Are you perhaps running a bat file to set environment variables for java when you start a new command prompt?  If you have environment variables set in your command window, you may need to edit the Environment Variables via the control panel to add them to the user or system variables.

Comment: actually these are my environment variables: http://i60.tinypic.com/2ec17j4.png.
As you can see I have JAVA_HOME and Path set properly, I think. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Path is for Windows to find programs to run CLASSPATH is for java to find classes to load.  This might help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: mmmm...ok, so, what am I supposed to do?